# how to set new guard for auth controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make multiple authentication in my laravel project.

I create new guard "admin" in my auth.php file but I don't know how to set new created guard in my authcontroller.

It always use "defaults" settings from my auth.php:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Answer (score 14):

1) If you wish to use newly created `admin` guard throughout the application, you can change the value in **defaults** of config file.

---

2) If it is only about **AuthController** that uses Laravel's in built Auth system, you can add this line in the *AuthController.php* and *PasswordController.php* :

```
protected $guard = 'admin';
```

Ref - Check **Guard Customization** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

---

3) If you wish to you a guard other than default one for any Auth related task, you can specify it manually like this :

```
// For route middleware
Route::get('profile', [
    'middleware' => 'auth:admin',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@show'
]);

// For manually logging the user in
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
    // Authenticated...
}

// To login specific user using eloquent model
Auth::guard('admin')->login($user);

// For getting logged in user
Auth::guard('admin')->user();

// To check if user is logged in
if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
    // Logged in
}
```

Ref - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.4+ uses the following in any Auth Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected function guard(){
   return Auth::guard('guard-name');
}
```

Comment: LoginController, RegisterController, and ResetPasswordController

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, so leave the default the way it is**

*So at the end of the day you want to be able to add the blow in all admin controllers*

```
public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('admin'); 
  }
```

**Follow the steps below and if you have any further questions, do let me know**

**1. Open config/auth.php**

Add `'admin' => ['driver' => 'session','provider' => 'admin',],` To guards

Then add `'admin' => ['driver' => 'eloquent','model' => App\Admin::class,],` To providers

Also `'admin' => ['provider' => 'admin','table' => 'password_resets','expire' => 60,],` For passwords

**2. Open app/Http/Middleware**

Then create AdminMiddleware.php in there (inside middleware folder)

Copy and paste below code in AdminMiddleware.php page

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware{ 
/**
* Handle an incoming request.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  \Closure  $next
* @return mixed
*/

 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard='admin')

  {

    if (!auth()->guard($guard)->check()) {
    //If admin is not authenticated the redirect to admin login page
    return redirect('/admin/login'); // it depends on how to have or set 
     // your route for admin login page
    }
      return $next($request);
   } 
   }
```

**3. Open app/Http/Kernel.php page**

Add

```
use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware; //from the middleware //Along 
//with other use;
```

Then add

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
] // protected already exists you only need to add 'admin' => 
// AdminMiddleware::class,
```

**4. In your admin controllers**

Add

```
public function __construct()
 {
     $this->middleware('admin'); 
 }
```

Just the way we have below for users or auth

```
public function __construct()
  {
     $this->middleware('auth');
  }
```

**5. Admin Model would be the same with User model just that the class would be diff i.e Admin**

**6 Admin route would be like this**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

// Login Routes...
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 
'AdminAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);

Route::post('login', ['uses' => 'AdminAuth\LoginController@login']);

Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'admin.logout', 'uses' => 
'AdminAuth\LoginController@logout']);


// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'admin.password.request', 'uses' 
=> 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);


 Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'admin.password.email', 'uses' 
 => 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);


 Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'admin.password.reset', ' 
 uses' => 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);


 Route::post('password/reset', ['uses' => 
 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);


//Dashboard
 Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'admin.dashboard', 'uses' => 
'AdminDashboardController@index']);
});
```

**7 Admin Login Controller**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuth;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

  class LoginController extends Controller
   {
  /*
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  - 
  ---
| Login Controller
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 - 
  ---
|
 | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
 | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
 |
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

 /**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
  * @var string
  */
 protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';

  /**
  * Create a new controller instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   // public function __construct()
   // {
  //     $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
  // }

    protected function guard()
   {

    return auth()->guard('admin');
    }

   public function showLoginForm()
   {

    return view('AdminAuth.login');
    }



   public function logout(Request $request)
  {
   auth()->guard('admin')->logout();

   $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('admin/login');
   }
   }
```

*Note that just the way we have Auth folder in Controller folder, we would also need AdminAuth the you would create the Login controller in there*

Answer (score -2):

You have to also register the guard in the `config\auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

     'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

admin is the guard name, provider is the TABLE-NAME

Comment: As said in the question, OP has already done that. The problem is that every route is using the guard defined in 'defaults'