# How do i create separate accounts for user and admin in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, user-registration

I am working on a project in laravel that needs the visitors to register as simple users to access some functionalities of the public section of the site with limited privileges and also needs to manage admin accounts which works on the admin section performing actions like creating, updating and deleting the content that appears on the public area.

How can I do this without necessary using user roles?

Comment: To maintain them separately, you can use multiple guards. Ref - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39009223/3113599

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way for this is to add a column `is_admin` to your `users` table (which can have value: 1 or 0).

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate column e.g. roles for admin and users. then create a separate admin middleware group. 
in `App/http/middleware/adminmiddleware.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if($request->user()->role=='Admin')
        {
           return $next($request);
        }
         return redirect('/home');
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Add the routes to protect

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\Adminmiddleware']], function () {
                // Routes for only admins   
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it... i just set a flag administrator and/or super_administrator which i use for defining some simple middleware to restrict route access (you can use middleware in controllers but i don't usually do that, i just stick middleware into routes).

See the docs on middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware
You can access Auth::user()->admin to check within the middleware, if you need more  info just ask i will copy paste some code i use.

For more complex roles, where users can access certain areas and some don't, you have to check out policies and authorization in laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization