# How to make multiple authorization in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two kind of users in Laravel: admin and user.

I need to build system when I can authorize in users profiles in Admin panel with admin permission.

Another words, I need to emulate authorization in profile user from admin panel.

Comment: Your question is little confusing. I guess you need multiple authentication for which you can create multiple guards. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39009223/3113599

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application, you may call the login method with the user instance.

```
Auth::login($user);
```

> To log a user into the application by their ID, you may use the loginUsingId metho

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#other-authentication-methods