# Auth guard is not define using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to do multiple authentication with different tables. And i am also adding these tables in auth.php But When i attempt to login the error show Auth[] not define.

```
'defaults' => [
    'users'=>[
        'guard' => 'users',
        'passwords' => 'users'
    ],
    'branch'=>[
        'guard' => 'branch',
        'password' => 'branch'
    ]
],


'guards' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'branch'=> [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'branch',
    ],
],



'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'branch' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Branch::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Your defaults array is wrong. It should not be a multi-dimensional array. Check https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L16

Comment: But I have two tables for checking authentication seprately. How i Define another table except user.

Comment: For that, you have already added a proper entry in guards array. You just need to specify guard while using authentication methods. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39009223/3113599