# What fields do I need to place in my migration for a class that implements Authenticatable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have 2 models that implement the authenticatable:

The default Laravel User:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

And I want for customers a seperate login therefore I do a seperate class for a seperate model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $fullname
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $phone
 *
 */
class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table='customer';

    protected $fillable = [
        'fullname',
        'user_id',
        'created_at'
    ];


    public function setFullnameAttribute($name)
    {
        $name=htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $this->attributes['fullname']=$name;
    }

    public function setEmailAttribute($email)
    {
        $email = trim($email);
        if(empty($email)){
            return;
        }

        // Controller does the validation therefore I do the sanitization here
        $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $this->attributes['email']=trim($email);
    }

    public function setPhoneAttribute($phone)
    {
        $phone = trim($phone);
        if(empty($phone)){
            return;
        }

        // Controller does the validation therefore I do the sanitization here
        $phone = preg_replace('/^[\+,\d]/',"",$phone);
        $this->attributes['phone']=trim($phone);
    }
}
```

For now customer has the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The table has been already created and **deployed** upon production with the following migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customer');

        Schema::create('customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('fullname');
            $table->string('email')->nullable(true);
            $table->string('phone')->nullable(true);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customer');
    }
};
```

Also I did place the nessesary settings upon `config/auth.php`:

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        // Default guard do not remove.
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'login',
        ],
        'customer'=>[
            'driver'=>'session',
            'provider'=>'customer'
        ]
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'login' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'customer'=>[
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Customer::class
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

Therefore what extra columns need to be populated upon the `customer` table in order for the login in the seperate table to work? A seperate page will authenticate the user located upon `customer` table.

Comment: Kindly follow the steps here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/78060101/13997698](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78060101/13997698) I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

When you have a separate table for customer authentication, you'll need to ensure that it follows the requirements for the Authenticatable contract. In Laravel, the Authenticatable contract requires certain fields to be present in the database table. For a basic authentication setup, you would typically need the following fields:

```
1) id: This is usually an auto-incrementing integer that serves as the primary key.
2) password: This field will store the hashed password for the user.
3) remember_token: If you plan to use the "Remember Me" functionality, you need a column to store a token for that.
```

you'll need to add these columns to your customer table. Modify your existing migration to include these columns:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('customer');

    Schema::create('customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('email')->nullable(true);
        $table->string('phone')->nullable(true);

        // Fields required for authentication
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken(); // optional
    });
}
```

With these changes, you should be able to use the customer table for authentication in your Laravel application. And You should check this blog to get more detailed code, It helps me lot https://techvblogs.com/blog/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel-9